# How to stop bagel dough deflating when it is handled between its rising place, the boiling pan, and its baking place?

Tags: baking, dough, bagels

When making bagels, what is an effective way to handle the dough between where it has sat when rising and the boiling pan, and between the boiling pan and whatever it bakes on, such that it does not deflate?

My dough rises nicely, but by the time I've boiled it and put it on a baking tray it has deflated.

Comment: Do your bagels really deflate after boiling? Mine are usually sturdy enough after boiling that I don't worry about it anymore.

Also, regular yeast, or sourdough bagels?

Comment: They deflate when I move them into and out of the pan. I sometimes use dried active yeast, sometimes cake yeast. I've looked at the pointy single-bagel "moulds" (really stands), but can only find them in silicone - too good an insulator for use in baking bagels, as some reviewers have reported. A metal version might be just the thing.

Comment: Please edit and put on your complete recipe and method.

Comment: Are you kneading long enough?  Bagels are usually in the 55- 65% hydration range...that is, a fairly stiff dough.

Comment: @GdD - No. I want answers to be as helpful as many readers as possible.

Comment: @moscafj - I think so. Everything's fine if I let the dough rise in blobs on a baking tray and make rolls without a hole. I'm using lye too.

Comment: @ruffle, this isn't a forum, it's a Q&A site. When you ask a question is needs to be specific, and that means posting your recipe and method.

Comment: Bagels deflating between boiling and oven aren't normal, so you're going to need to explain your method and timings or you won't get useful advice.